# single query for fetching data from multiple collection in Mongodb/Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

In a `Node.js` App, i use `Mongodb`/`Mongoose`. `MongoDB` doesn't has Joins, and this is a big problem for me. because i store data in separate collections. i have two collections. `Users` and `Books`. i need a query like this:

```
SELECT Books.name FROM Users,Books WHERE Users.name='john' and Books.lang='en'
```

im sure that we cannot do this by one single Mongoose query. Mongoose populate has also lots of problems. for example if i do this:

```
Users.find({user_name:'john'}).pupulate({path:'books', match:{lang:'en'}})
```

and if i change this code to this, it gets to another problem:

```
Users.find({user_name:'john'}).pupulate({path:'books', match:{lang:'en'}}).limit(6)
```

it fetches first 6 users item and then populate books, if there no population then result will be null. i need fetch first 6 item that belong to an specific user and has an english book.

With this code, All users with name of john will be fetched and a few of them has a book with english language. imagine users with name john is 1 million and one of them has an english book! we have to fetch that huge data and with a secondary block of code, filter that one item. its not clear and good way.

is there any other way? i has a lot of search about this but no good result. in this scenario what annoys me is fetching all users and then filter it again. this can be an slow architecture. whats the best way to me? what can i do.

i'm wondering a database engine that claims to be an enterprise one has this disadvantage. other people doesn't has this problem? there is something i'm missing?

Comment: its a pseudocode, what i want is  this: fetch first 6 item that belong to an specific user that has an english book.  i need a clear way. i know we cant do this by single query, i'm ok with filtering with secondary code, but i'm not ok with fetching 1 million record and chose one of them. it gets very slow i think.

Comment: can you give me an example here? i don't understand your mean, and also didn't find a solution for my answer according to documentation you give me

Comment: A bit late, sorry. My comments were absurd since mongoose is using the ID of the second document. You'll need to save some Book info on User or viceversa or "reverse" the relation and search first on Books and then filter by User. Remember that "populate" is a mongoose feature, not anything "native" with mongodb to create a formal relation between entities.